# Which subsets of the real numbers can you play Sylver coinage on?

Tags: number-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

For a set $S$ of real numbers, we say that you can play [sylver's coinage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylver_coinage) on it if for any infinite sequence of $x_n \in \mathbb R$, there is some $N$ such that $x_N$ is a sum of previous terms. For example, you can play on $\mathbb N$ (which corresponds to regular Sylver's coinage). Or you can play on $\mathbb Z$. You can't play on $\mathbb R$ though, since $1$, $\pi$, $\pi^2$, $\pi^3$, $\dots$ is a bad infinite sequence.

So, is there some way we can characterize which sets in $P(\mathbb R)$ you can play on.

Some examples:

- Any finite set $S$
- A subset of any playable set
- The union of two playble sets

Comment: I think I've only seen it called "Sylver coinage" (with or without capitalization). Do you know of a source calling it "sylver's coinage"?

Comment: @MarkS. How about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2682956/49592)? Feel free to edit it though.

Comment: In the first sentence I suppose you mean $x_n\in S$? I don't think your fourth point is correct - taking $S=\{1,\sqrt 2\}$, its closure under addition will contain infinite descending sequence of positive numbers, and for such a sequence no element is a sum of earlier ones.

Comment: @Wojowu ah, you're correct